# Where are property descriptor objects stored?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, propertydescriptor

I know that you can obtain a property descriptor object 
of a certain property '`prop`' of a certain object `obj` with 
`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,"prop");`. 
I was just wondering: Where are these objects stored? 
Are they stored internally within an object or .... elsewhere?
I tried to find them in developer tools but with no luck.

Comment: From my reading of the spec, calls to this function [end up here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarygetownproperty), where it builds up the return from a bunch of different `[[internal properties]]`. Those properties don't _have_ to be exposed to the end runtime, but some implementations may make them available, for example in the dev tools.  Your milage may vary...

Comment: They're stored wherever any particular implementation chooses to store them, or more likely, they are constructed when asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property descriptor objects does not exist unless explicitly requested. They are created ad-hoc when you [call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor). 
So following code:

```
var foo = {bar:'foo'}
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'bar') === Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'bar');
```

Always evaluate to false.

So as we see (both code and specification), property descriptor objects are not stored, but created on demand.

So where are `writable`, `configurable`, `value`, `get`, `set`... atributtes stored? Specification doesn't require them to be exposed to user code... [Here is C++ definition for V8 PropertyDescriptor class](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/bc2e393b4cc474a817c3fc5f9c5d7e58636f6ae5/src/property-descriptor.h) - it seems like every property occupy one byte.

And if you want check if property is writable, configurable or similar, Firefox console allow you to do so (but only if property isn't writable or has getter/setter):
[image: Firefox DevTools]

Comment: But doesn't *any Object* - when compared to another Object - return false? For example  `[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` is also `false`

Comment: Objects are compared by reference ("it's **the same** object"), not by value ("it's **identical** object"). Eg. `var a = {}, b=a; a===b; // true`